# XSLT- concat string values

Tags: xslt

My data is coming in this way:

```
<ZR4.25>
<ZR4.25.1>ABCD</ZR4.25.1>
<ZR4.25.2>DEFG</ZR4.25.2>
<ZR4.25.3>PQRA</ZR4.25.3>
 ............
</ZR4.25>
```

Now I want to concatenate each sub-fields of  using foreach loop so that, the output will be as follows:

```
ABCD, DEFG, PQRA
```

I can do it without using for-each, but how to do it with for loop?Any help, please?

Comment: Can you show your existing code please, to show how you are currently doing it with using for-each? Thanks!

Comment: I am doing it without for-each just by concatenating, I wanted to do it with for-each

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just have a template match the child nodes it and grab out the values, e.g.

```
<xsl:template match="/ZR4.25/*">
  <xsl:value-of select="." />
  <xsl:if test="following-sibling::*">,</xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

You're telling it to get all the text out of those nodes, and if there's a following sibling to append a comma.